# Option to activate Help text

Tags: files, cursor, file-properties

Is there any help text option in Ubuntu? By this i mean as we see in windows if u hover the cursor over files u get basic details of the file in a small text box near the cursor. Is there any such option in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

You can install `gnome-sushi` which provides quick file previews.

To use it, select a file in Nautilus and then press the SPACE bar. It actually doesn't depend on Nautilus so other file managers can make use of it.It is capable of previewing documents, PDFs, video and audio files.

To install, open a terminal and run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-sushi
```

For more information and a demo video, visit http://www.ubuntugeek.com/gnome-sushi-quick-previewer-for-nautilus.html.

**Off-topic:** In case you're wondering how can you use nautilus scripts and what scripts are available, this link has 125 different scripts that can enhance your experience: http://www.ubuntu-unleashed.com/2007/09/125-nautilus-scripts-to-simplify.html.

Comment: Thanx for ur first tip. Regarding the second one I dont know what does it mean by scripts I am new with Ubuntu. an u pls be more specific regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably install a nautilus script which would do the trick.

Comment: Is that available on software center. Is it the same as Nautilus scripts manager.

Comment: I believe the NSM is a program which allows you to activate and deactivate the scripts you have. As for finding scripts I think you either have to make them yourself or find them from other people on the Internet. There are so many things people want programs to do that Ubuntu couldn't possibly keep all of the scripts that have been developed for nautilus.